# SQLite - how to query spatial reference?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am adding points to the map, their location I am saving into the databse. When I click on a previously added point on the map, I want to perform SQLite query, whethere I have clicked on some point. Obviously, you are not 100% correct when clicking on item on display. I have invented a squared area, which will accept click as a it is a desired point (more info is seen on the image). I have divided this area to four quadrants for SQlite query - if it is accepted as a Point selection, I have to put my finger only and only in one of those quadrants.

[image]

I am using SQL statement for figuring out, if I have clicked on the point or not:

```
cursor=db.query("points_details2", null ,"(location_X <="+cXplus+" AND location_Y >="+cYminus+") OR (location_X >="+cXminus+" AND location_Y >="+cYminus+") OR (location_X <="+cXplus+" AND location_Y <="+cYplus+") OR (location_X >="+cXminus+" AND location_Y <="+cYplus+")", null, null, null, null);
                            Log.d("POINT", "Cursor "+cursor.getColumnName(0));
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.d("POINT","data is: "+cursor.getInt(0)+", "+cursor.getString(1)+", "+cursor.getString(2)+", "+cursor.getDouble(3)+", "+cursor.getDouble(4));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
```

And the boundaries are specified as:

```
double cXplus=coord_X+5;
double cXminus=coord_X-5;
double cYplus=coord_Y+5;
double cYminus=coord_Y-5;
```

So here is the boundary 5, coord_X and coord_Y are coordinates of my screen click with my finger.

Here is the thing - Am I using bad approach? This SQL statement I have provided is not working, and I don't know why. Can anyone help me in this case? Thanks

Comment: They should all be `AND`, no? Don't you want the point to be inside ALL four corners of the square?

Comment: Oh, man, thanks a lot. I have overseen this... Make this an answer, I will mark it as a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should all be `AND`! You want the point to be inside ALL four corners of the square.

i.e.

```
(location_X <="+cXplus+" AND location_Y >="+cYminus+") AND (location_X >="+cXminus+" AND location_Y >="+cYminus+") AND (location_X <="+cXplus+" AND location_Y <="+cYplus+") AND (location_X >="+cXminus+" AND location_Y <="+cYplus+")
```

Comment: And one more question, do you know how to make a circle boundaries instead of square?

Comment: There is no simple way. You would have to test your point to be inside  every `dA`, where your Cartesian coordinate is `(x_c + r*cos(A),y_c + r*sin(A))`, for `0 < A < 360`, `(x_c,y_c)` is circle center.

Comment: Copying other people's answers is not considered good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two bounding lines on each side you can simplify to:

```
"(location_X <="+cXplus+" AND location_X >="+cXminus+" AND location_Y >="+cYminus+" 
AND location_Y <="+cYplus")"
```